# How to tell if your key hinge (retainer clip) is broken?

Tags: keyboard

I own a MacBook Air 2013 and I recently broke my "comma" key.

I had to pull it out to clean underneath and I think I was a bit rough, so one of the hooks in the key cap broke. I put it back on and it seems to work but the key pops out often. My concern is not with the key cap, I'm worried about the hinge. How can I tell the hinge is not broken? How can I know if I didn't break it either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In researching your question, I discovered that you can [purchase individual replacement MacBook Air keyboard keys](http://www.replacementlaptopkeys.com/servlet/the-24298/2012-Macbook-Air-Laptop/Detail), specified as manufactured by Apple.
Hope this helps.

But to answer your question, I would acquire a known good key hinge to examine and compare to the key hinge in question. This should allow you to determine if your key hinge is broken.

Comment: Yeah, thks. I've already bought a new key cap and a new hinge. It seems to me that the one I have is working. The hinge is holding the key cap well, but the key cap is attached to the hinge by 3 pins, since I broke one. I just wanted to know becuase I can't really tell if the hinge has been damaged or not. Thks.

Comment: I know what you mean. When something is that small, I can't tell what is going on and I'm simply amazed that someone was able to design that. If I have any talent, it is certainly only in the operation of and not the understanding or engineering of very small machines. How did they come up with that?